# Why is my routing prefix not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my browser's address bar, I've got the following input:

```
http://localhost:55105/Tasks/UpdateStatus/8/1
```

However, it is not hitting my controller method when I debug.

```
    [Route("Tasks/UpdateStatus/{id}/{status}")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UpdateStatus(int id, int status)
    {
        Task task = db.Tasks.Find(id);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            task.Status = status;
            db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(task);
    }
```

Getting following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action method expects the parameters to be passed as **POST** and the via the way you are doing in the browser **url** it is get request as parameters are part of url as query string. What you need is a form in your view and post the values via form.

Make sure that you are sending the data as post method for you request.

For just to understand you can try renaming the `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpGet]` and see it will work, but that's not the way for the above use case as you are updating data in database so you should be using **POST** not **GET**

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So I'm trying this in my JavaScript: `$.post("Tasks/UpdateStatus", { id: "8", status: "1" });` and I'm getting 404 not found.

Comment: Turns out `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` was part of the issue. So should I use [Authorize] for this particular controller action instead or is there a way to satisfy `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` when using in JavaScript? Also, turns out I didn't need to use the `route attribute`